# Windows PowerShell returns error for "python --version" even though I have it installed

Tags: windows, installation, powershell, python, packages

For a very long time I've used python to code. I installed Anaconda and I use Visual Studio Code to write the code. I want to download a new package using pip, and following the ["Installing packages"](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/installing-packages/#ensure-you-can-run-python-from-the-command-line) from the python documentation I first checked if I had python in the system by typing "python --version" on Windows PowerShell. I assumed that I had python, but I get the following error message:

[image]

Do I have to install Python directly from python.org even though I have it on Anaconda?

Answer (score 2):

I fixed it! Miraculously I added a directory to the line, so it looked like this:

[image]

Don't ask me the odds of success for stitching a directory and a line off the internet because I can barely comprehend it myself.

Answer (score 0):

I think your Python location is missing from `$Env:Path`.
try:

```
echo $Env:Path
```

and check if the directory is in that list. Most likely not. then you will have to add it to the path variable.

```
$Env:Path += ";C:\Users\EspenOliver\Anaconda3\python"
refreshenv
```

Comment: Ok, I've done this and I can now find python in the list when I type `echo $Env:Path`. But if I now type `python --version` it returns the same error as before.

Comment: @EspenSales Does `python3 --versoin` work?